# Custom generated filename with Angular Cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

With Angular-cli the builded filename is main.[hash].bundle.js when use `ng build -prod`
Is it possible to remove the hash form this filename. So just `main.bundle.js`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's now supported via a command option as of beta.25.

> This allows the output filename hashes to be configured during a build via a new build command option `--output-hashing`. There are four possible values:
>
> `none`: no hashing performed
>
> `media`: only add hashes to files processed via [url|file]-loaders
>
> `bundles`: only add hashes to the output bundles
>
> `all`: add hashes to both media and bundles
>
> none is the default for the development target.
> all is the default for the production target.

More details [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3885).

Answer (score 12):

I added the following script element for production build in the package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "prod" : "ng build --prod --output-hashing=none --base-href=./"
}
```

then running

```
npm run prod
```

would build the dist folder without hash and also includes the ./ as base-href so that files are loaded relative to current directory.

Answer (score 8):

As per my understanding the `hash` is used for production build so that one wont run into browser cache issues, and the users wont have to clear cache before using the new deployment.

I doubt that `angular-cli` team would give us an option to configure that, we have to wait to check that.

Meanwhile if you want to customize your build process you may build the webpack config yourself.

Also, the CLI team has indicated that there will be a few webpack plugins which will help in creating own webpack configuration. Checkout [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack).

More details [here, WEBPACK: AN INTRODUCTION](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, as I was actually wondering what the reason behind the hashing is.

Comment: Regarding production - it's definitely for caching but don't forget to consider the case where someone **already** has your old site open and you deploy a new version of all the files. If you delete the old files from the webserver then the new person will get 404 errors if they try to lazy load something (a lazy module) that isn't there anymore. So if the new deployment is 'reasonably compatible' with the old one (server API / image filenames etc.) then consider leaving the old files for a period of time so new users don't get 404s.

Comment: This will of course depend on what your software is - and a 404 can be a good thing if you want people kicked off - but then you ideally should handle that.

Comment: Thanks. If the filenames have random strings in it then what is the way to include them in html files via script tag? Can you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62269386/problems-in-moving-from-development-mode-to-production-mode

Answer (score 3):

try using:

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing none
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't do this with the cli, but you can come out of it and use standard Webpack.

Run `ng eject` in your project and it will build up a proper Webpack configuration and scripts.

You can read up on it in the Wiki on GitHub.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject

Once you've got the config you can do what @tallaxes suggested.

Answer (score -3):

Remove `[chunkhash]` from the following lines in `angular-cli/models/webpack-build-production.js` (under `node_modules` if patching, under `packages` if forking):

```
filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js',
sourceMapFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map',
chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].chunk.js'
```

Comment: Thnx. But I can't edit the node_modules, because this is builded automatically