# How to add current datetime as version number in angular build hash file on index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I am facing caching issue with my Angular app. I have used several approach but issue is still there.
For creating the build, I am using following command.

ng build --prod --output-hashing=all --aot

Can we add version number after hash file name like as below.

```
<script src='runtime.834594739.js?v=12345678'></script>
```

Please suggest, how to add version number with build file which auto adds in index.html file on runtime.

Thanks

Comment: The `834594739 ` is the hash generated by the CLI. Why do you want to add `12345678 `?

Comment: I would like to add my version number as well that's why.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718803/custom-generated-filename-with-angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

The correct param is `--outputHashing`, not `--output-hashing`.
Just focus on -- (double hyphen)

[Documentation](https://angular.io/cli/build#arguments).

Angular manages that on its own, just use it correctly.

Comment: Both will work.

But after using this, my file is still being cached. After deploying the new version, we are able to see old file data.

Comment: Please share the output of your `build` command. If the cache busting is enabled, there is absolutely no reason for it to not work.